# Mcrypt, PHP/MYSQL and web form not working for some entries

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I have a MYSQL database with a column of data of which is encrypted using AES_ENCRYPT. I also have a form, where the user inputs some of this data, it's encrypted using Mcrypt (see below for code used) and verified against the MYSQL database, then if there's a match it returns true.

For most cases this works fine. However, for a small number of submissions, I get a failure in the connection to the database. It always fails for this same data, but if I try different data it is successful. So there is something unique about the data, which is causing it to fail and I can't spot a pattern. The data is the same length of characters, just a different combination of letters and numbers, i.e. hr152698 or tq452698

```
$mode=MCRYPT_MODE_ECB;
            $enc=MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;
            $numblock=floor(strlen($id) / 16);
            $pad_len= 16-(strlen($id) % 16);
            $id=str_pad($id, (16*(floor(strlen($id) / 16)+1)), 
chr($pad_len));
            $encrypted_id=mcrypt_encrypt($enc, $ky, $id, $mode, 
mcrypt_create_iv( mcrypt_get_iv_size($enc, $mode), MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
```

I'm wondering if it could be to do with the number 16 in the code above. Perhaps it needs to be higher if certain text is entered? The MYSQL column that holds this data is setup as: varbinary(25).

Regards
Mark

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: Hi Mark, I do not have a lot of experience with encryption so I can only give you a guess: It sounds a bit like you are having an encoding problem that can affect multiple locations (the PHP file, the database, any view files with the forms). It might be worth checking also by checking if you have any special characters in the texts that are not working well.

Comment: After the above code runs, this next segment runs:

`$query = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE logon = '$encrypted_id'";
                mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');`

So the error I see on my webpage when submitting the form is 'Error querying database'. The text I'm submitting that gets put through the Mycrypt is only made up of alphanumeric characters. 95% of the time it works, just 5% of the time, I get the error and it's repeatable with the same text entered, so it's not just a random connection error.

Comment: How about you inspect the database for *what error exactly occurred* instead of taking stabs into the dark? → http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Thank you... I generated the error and got: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'yC3u�Zp�'' at line 1'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions above, it got me thinking along the right lines. I wasn't escaping the Mycrypt result, so I was generating some invalid characters, causing the MYSQL error above.

I used: `$encrypted_id=mysql_real_escape_string($encrypted_id);` to resolve.

Comment: Actually needed to use this... `$encrypted_id=$db->real_escape_string($encrypted_id);` to work with MYSQLi